# How do I create a "Windows to go" bootable USB to use windows on a USB without installing it on my Linux machine?

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb, windows, burning

I want to burn a Windows ISO file to a USB but I want to use it without installing it this can be done by burning the iso file on the USB with the (Windows to go) option.
The problem is that this option as I know can be chosen in rufus and rufus is only on windows I want to burn a Windows ISO option with the Windows to go option on using ubuntu Linux.

I tried to use WoeUSB-ng on my Linux machine, but it didn't have this option as expected as you can see in the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zmZV.png)

Note: I'm trying to burn Windows 10.

sorry if you couldn't understand my bad English.

Comment: You can't. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/889335/create-windows-to-go-usb-from-ubuntu on a method.